# Can you keep an element from moving when switching views besides a NavigationBar?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol, uitoolbar

I am trying to have a UINavigation controller with a title view the logo for the app, and a UISegmentedControl below it, however, it is too tall to fit in the Navigation bar.  Is there any way to have a toolbar with a UISegmentedControl that is under the navigation bar and doesn't move when you switch views by selecting a Segment? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting animated to NO when switching views and keeping the same UIsegmentedcontrol within a toolbar under the NavigationBar on all three of my views